# iTunes song in Playlist but not in "Music"

Tags: itunes, mp3, music

First of all: I disabled Apple Music in the settings now I have an album of "The Weeknd" like so (Bought via apple):

I sync all my songs via good old cable syncing and a Playlist which is the source for my iphone.

[image]

But there is only one Song. Now if I go to my playlist which is synced to my computer. All songs are there:

[image]

Why is that? Isn't the "My Music" supposed to show every! tune on my phone?

Comment: Perhaps you put all the songs you liked in the playlist or you change your settings recently so it glitched it a bit what computer r u using?

Comment: Yeah I put al the songs into this playlist. But shouldn't "Meine Music" show every title on the iphone? I use a mac (El Capitan)

Answer (score 0):

The only song that you can see is "can not feel my face". This is because the others song has explicit content. So you have to go on your iPhone settings and disable restrictions.